# C++: Diamond concerns

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

Simple question:
Will this hierarchy cause a DP?

```
//Abstract base class
class A {
    //Implement pure virtual methods with a default definition.
    //Pure virtual methods are still declared pure virtual.
};

//Abstract derived class
class B : public A {
    //Define pure virtual methods with a default definition.
    //Pure virtual methods are still declared pure virtual.
};

//Abstract base class
class C {
    //Define pure virtual methods with a default definition.
    //Pure virtual methods are still declared pure virtual.
};

//Concrete class
class D : public B, public C {
    //Implement all methods from D, B, and C
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Draw the picture; all bases are unique:

```
A
|
V
B   C
 \ /
  V
  D
```

The "diamond problem" only pertains to ambiguous base classes due to multiple repeated bases, e.g. if `D` were to derive from both `A -> B` and `A -> C`:

```
No-diamond-problematic:                 Virtually-inherited diamond:

        A   A                                         A
        |   |                                       v/ \v
        B   C                                       B   C
         \ /                                         \ /
          V                                           V
          D                                           D
```